# PHP SESSION won't maintain after header() called

Tags: php, session

This has been asked several times in various flavors, but never answered; it's driving me crazy.

Page 1:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["testVariable"] = "test";
header("Location: http://www.mysite.com/page2.php");
```

Page 2:

```
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Result:

```
Array ()
```

Any ideas? If I echo(session_id()) on both pages, the ID is different. 
Also, if I comment out the header call, and hit page2.php manually, the session variables are displayed correctly.

Comment: Are you staying on the exact same domain with this? If not, the session will not carry on

Comment: Can you show the URL Page 1 is on?

Comment: Are you accessing the first page from `http://mysite.com` as opposed to `http://www.mysite.com`?

Comment: That's ALL the code, right? Not just part of the code you're testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Greg said:

> Are you accessing the first page from http://mysite.com as opposed to http://www.mysite.com?

Comment: Greg, why don't you post this answer and Jon can approve it and you can have the points. (Precious, precious points.)